# ERROR_WINHTTP_INCORRECT_HANDLE_STATE from WinHttpQueryHeaders

Tags: c++, winapi, error-handling, winhttp

I'm trying to build a small browser using the WinHTTP API, and I'm trying to handle credentials & authentication requests. I'm using this diagram for better understanding:

[image: diagram]

When I'm trying to `GET` a URL that requires authentication, I'm getting an error from this function (`ERROR_WINHTTP_INCORRECT_HANDLE_STATE`) from the call to `WinHttpQueryHeaders()` and I'm not sure why:

```cpp
void WinHttpCheck::init(LPCWSTR method, const char* cUrl, LPSTR data, DWORD dataLen, LPCWSTR additional headers)
{
    isAborted = false;
    bool postFlow = false;
    
    // Create & Initialize the URL_COMPONENTS structure.
    URL_COMPONENTS urlComp;
    ZeroMemory(&urlComp, sizeof(urlComp));
    urlComp.dwStructSize = sizeof(urlComp);

    // Set required component lengths to non-zero 
    // so that they are cracked.
    urlComp.dwSchemeLength = (DWORD)-1;
    urlComp.dwHostNameLength = (DWORD)-1;
    urlComp.dwUrlPathLength = (DWORD)-1;
    urlComp.dwExtraInfoLength = (DWORD)-1;

    if (lstrcmpW(method, M_POST) == 0) {
        printf("********** Init Post flow! **********\n");
        postFlow = true;
    }

    LPCWSTR lpcUrl = cStringT_convert(cUrl); // convert char* to LPCWSTR
    if (!WinHttpCrackUrl(lpcUrl, (DWORD)wcslen(lpcUrl), 0/*flags*/, &urlComp)) {
        reportErrorAndExit("WinHttpCrackUrl");
    } else {
        printUrlComponent(urlComp);
    }

    // return just the host name with no path or "http://" prefix
    LPCWSTR validateAndConvertOutput = validateAndConvertUrl(cUrl);
    
    // impl down
    st.request = createHttpRequestHandle(validateAndConvertOutput, method, urlComp);

    if (st.request) {
        printf("********** open request succeed! **********\n");

        // handle WinHttpSendRequest params here in case of credentials request
        LPCWSTR headers = WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS;
        LPVOID optionalData = WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA;
        DWORD HeadersLen = 0,
            optionalLen = 0,
            totalLen = 0;

        if (postFlow) { // post/put data request
            optionalData = (LPVOID)data;
            optionalLen = dataLen;
            totalLen = dataLen;
            if (additionalHeaders) {
                HeadersLen = (ULONG)-1L;
                headers = additionalHeaders;
            }
        }

        if (!WinHttpSendRequest(st.request, headers, HeadersLen, optionalData, optionalLen, totalLen, 0)) {
            st.bResults = WinHttpQueryHeaders(st.request,
                WINHTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE |
                WINHTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER,
                NULL,
                &st.dwStatusCode,
                &st.dwSize,
                NULL);
            if (st.bResults)
                handleStatusCode(authForm);
            else
                reportErrorAndExit("WinHttpQueryHeaders - NEW"); // HERE: Error code 12019 has occurred from function WinHttpQueryHeaders - NEW
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

createHttpRequestHandle:

```
HINTERNET WinHttpCheck::createHttpRequestHandle(LPCWSTR& url, const LPCWSTR& method, URL_COMPONENTS urlComp)
{
    // obtain a session handle.
    st.session = WinHttpOpen(L"PTC_EDGE_INTEGRATED_BROWSER",
        WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS,
        0);

    // Specify an HTTP server.
    if (st.session) {
        printf("********** open succeed! **********\n");
        printf("trying to connect to url: %S\n", url);
        st.connect = WinHttpConnect(st.session, url,
            urlComp.nPort, 0/*reserved - must be 0*/);
    }
    else
        reportErrorAndExit("WinHttpOpen");

    // Create an HTTP request handle.
    if (st.connect) {
        printf("********** connect succeed! **********\n");
        st.request = WinHttpOpenRequest(st.connect, method,
            L"/debug.txt", NULL/*default version - HTTP/1.1*/,
            WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
            WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
            WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE);
    }
    else {
        reportErrorAndExit("WinHttpConnect");
    }

    return st.request;
}
```

The error code is 12019 = `ERROR_WINHTTP_INCORRECT_HANDLE_STATE`.

The `URL_COMPONENT` content looks like this:

[image]

I looked for this in [Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/error-messages) but all it says is:

> The requested operation cannot be carried out because the handle supplied is not in the correct state.

Can I have some help for a better understanding of "handle's correct state"?

Comment: just to remark, when I'm using ``GET`` method it's not in ```postFlow```

Answer (score 0):

The only place I see you calling `WinHttpQueryHeaders()` is after `WinHttpSendRequest()` **fails**, which is not a valid time to call it.

As is clearly stated in the [`WinHTTPQueryHeaders` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpqueryheaders):

> `[in] hRequest`
>
> `HINTERNET` request handle returned by `WinHttpOpenRequest`. **`WinHttpReceiveResponse` must have been called for this handle and have completed before `WinHttpQueryHeaders` is called.**

Also, as the [`WinHttpReceiveResponse()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpreceiveresponse) says:

> The `WinHttpReceiveResponse` function waits to receive the response to an HTTP request initiated by `WinHttpSendRequest`. **When `WinHttpReceiveResponse` completes successfully, the status code and response headers have been received and are available for the application to inspect using `WinHttpQueryHeaders`.** An application must call `WinHttpReceiveResponse` before it can use `WinHttpQueryDataAvailable` and `WinHttpReadData` to access the response entity body (if any).

Even the [`WinHTTPSendRequest()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpsendrequest) says:

> Even when WinHTTP is used in asynchronous mode, that is, when `WINHTTP_FLAG_ASYNC` has been set in `WinHttpOpen`, this function can operate either synchronously or asynchronously. In either case, if the request is sent successfully, the application is called back with the completion status set to `WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_SENDREQUEST_COMPLETE`. The `WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR` completion indicates that the operation completed asynchronously, but failed. **Upon receiving the `WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_SENDREQUEST_COMPLETE` status callback, the application can start to receive a response from the server with `WinHttpReceiveResponse`. Before then, no other asynchronous functions can be called, otherwise, `ERROR_WINHTTP_INCORRECT_HANDLE_STATE` is returned.**

You can even see in the diagram you posted that `WinHttpReceiveResponse()` precedes `WinHttpQueryHeaders()`.

So, it makes perfect sense why you are getting an error about the HTTP session being in an invalid state when you try retrieve the response headers. The request failed to send, and no response was received which can be queried.

Comment: You're probably right but at the end I implemented this functions asynchronous using `WinHttpSetCallback` as it explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa383138(v=vs.85))